# CSS binding with $index when setting multiple classes

Tags: knockout.js

With this binding

```
css: 'item' + $index()
```

I get this output

```
class="item0"
class="item1"
class="item2"
...
```

I'm not able to use this when binding multiple classes like below, a syntax error is thrown because `:` is expected instead of `+`. Any hints?

```
css: { 'item' + $index(), 'active': $index() == 0 }
```

A workaround is to use attribute binding, but if possible I'd like to avoid that because there are existing classes set already, so I'd have to include those in the binding.

```
attr: { 'class': 'slider-item item' + $index() + ($index() == 0 ? ' active' : '') }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also do the same string concatenation in the `css` binding:

```
css: 'item' + $index() + ($index() == 1 ? ' active' : '')
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CsSDR/)

Comment: Didn't think of that, it works indeed and it's cleaner. +1 for now, will accept if it turns out to be the best possible solution.

Comment: If you want to set dynamic class like item0, item1 etc. you cannot use an object literal as the css binding parameter, so your only options is to use string concat to build your classes either in `attr` or in the `css` binding.